# how to set default image in views.py django

Tags: python, django

I have this login inside my views.py, my question is **How do i set a default value of an image if the system detect that the picture is None?**

```
image = request.FILES['image1'] or None
fs = FileSystemStorage()
filename = fs.save(image.name, image)
uploaded_file_url = fs.url(filename)

image2 = request.FILES['image2'] or None
fs = FileSystemStorage()
filename = fs.save(image2.name, image2)
uploaded_file_url = fs.url(filename)

image3 = request.FILES['image3'] or None
fs = FileSystemStorage()
filename = fs.save(image3.name, image3)
uploaded_file_url = fs.url(filename)

insert_data = Product(
    image = image,
    image2 = image2,
    image3=image3,
    ....
)
insert_data.save()
```

in models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images', null=True, blank=True, default='default1.jpg')
    image2 = models.ImageField(upload_to='images', null=True, blank=True, default='default1.jpg')
    image3 = models.ImageField(upload_to='images', null=True, blank=True, default='default1.jpg')
    .....
```

this is my traceback

```
Traceback:

File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\LastProject\OnlinePalengke\customAdmin\views.py" in InsertProduct
  133.     image2 = request.FILES['image2'] or None

File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\datastructures.py" in __getitem__
  80.             raise MultiValueDictKeyError(key)

Exception Type: MultiValueDictKeyError at /InsertProduct/
Exception Value: 'image2'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't provide the image, then Product should be able to save default file. So what you can do is:

```
# You can use fs.save() only, you don't have to define multiple times
fs = FileSystemStorage()

image = request.FILES.get('image1') # set automatically to None when MultiValueDictKeyError

# If image is not None only save, else leave it as None
if image not None:
    filename = fs.save(image.name, image)
    uploaded_file_url = fs.url(filename)

# When None is passed to image, as null is true default value will be set
insert_data = Product(
    image = image,
    image2 = image2,
    image3=image3,
    ....
)
insert_data.save()
```

From django_docs of [Field.default](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.default): The default is also used when the field is set to None.

*Note: `image` is only a sample, you can do same for `image2`, `image3` and so on.

Comment: 'method' object is not subscriptable i received this error

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `request.FILES['image1'] or None` to `request.FILES.get('image1')`
and make changes accordingly to other 2 places.

`dict.get('key')` return value in the dict against key, if no such key exists, it returns `None`

also make uploading image code lines on conditional,

```
fs = FileSystemStorage() #make it one time declaration

if image:
    filename = fs.save(image.name, image)
    uploaded_file_url = fs.url(filename)
```

Comment: I think you did not include sthg new to the answer, I gave. Please don't do sthg like this again. If you want to explain somethings then let me know that i should explain. I would appreciate that. Anyway, peace out!!!